# LinearLayout won't fill the width of the screen

Tags: android, layout, dynamic

I've been working through a bunch of examples on StackOverflow to create a dynamic layout. 
I've made some headway but have now stalled on a particular bug.

How do I make this code fill the width of the parent?

```
    LinearLayout masterLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.button_views);

        for(int i=0; i<(launchers.length/3+1); i++){
        layout[i] = new LinearLayout(getBaseContext());
        layout[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        layout[i].setWeightSum(3);


            for(int i1=0; i1<(3); i1++){

                launchers[i1] = new Button(this);
                launchers[i1].setText(titles[i1]);
                launchers[i1].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                launchers[i1].setOnClickListener(this);
                layout[i].addView(launchers[i1]);
            }
            masterLayout.addView(layout[i]);
```

The code works MOSTLY as desired, the part i'm missing is the buttons being an even width and being spaced evenly across the full length of the screen.

Comment: It is not really clear to me, do you want the button (launchers) evenly spread or want them to have it the same width as its parent view? If so double check 
launchers[i1].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
Should be then
launchers[i1].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

Comment: thanks for the reply. The outcome should be 3 launchers evenly spread per row over 3 rows. When I change launchers[i1]. params to FILL_PARENT then i get one button in the row stretched across the screen. Not the outcome I'm wanting.

Comment: can you attach images, what you are trying to achieve and what you currently have? I dont quite get what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: I just figured it out... discovered that there is a weight attribute within LinearLayout.LayoutParams. Will post as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that LinearLayout.LayoutParams has an option for weight at the end of it. Here is the final code for a dynamic button layout system that fits the width of the screen.

```
    LinearLayout masterLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.button_views);

    for(int i=0; i<(launchers.length/3+1); i++){
    layout[i] = new LinearLayout(getBaseContext());
    layout[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    layout[i].setWeightSum(3);


        for(int i1=0; i1<(3); i1++){

            launchers[i1] = new Button(this);
            launchers[i1].setText(titles[i1]);
            launchers[i1].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
            launchers[i1].setOnClickListener(this);
            layout[i].addView(launchers[i1]);
        }
        masterLayout.addView(layout[i]);
```

What would help would be a way to allow the buttons to always be square if anyone wants to have a go at that...